# always visible tooltip on google chart on page load?

Tags: charts, tooltip, google-visualization

Is there any way to make google charts tooltip always visible, no matter where the mouse pointer is?
it should be constantly on after page load

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best I could come up with is:

http://jsfiddle.net/xDfLd/

But if you interact with the chart (ie, click on different pie segments, or different line segments), the tooltip will disappear. Setting `enableInteractivity:false` I'll file a bug that tooltips and selections should still display when interactivity is off anyway.

Comment: I added other rows to selection and it seems to work: chart.setSelection([{row:4,column:null}, {row:3,column:null}, {row:2,column:null} , {row:1,column:null} , {row:0,column:null}]);

Answer (score 3):

I combined what Jeremy posted with Yasen's comment and came to this solution:

```
var options = {
  enableInteractivity: false,
  selectionMode: 'multiple',
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'selection'
  }
};

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function(e) {
  var selected_rows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < your_total_number_of_rows - 1; i++) {
    selected_rows.push({row: i, column: null});
  }
  chart.setSelection(selected_rows);
});

chart.draw(data, options);
```

This shows all the tooltips on load and prevents the user from messing around with them. Works great with the Pie Chart.

Answer (score 2):

Use tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' } when defining options for the chart.